# How JSF el expression works and when a JSF variable resolver will be involved while evaluating any JSF exprestion?

Tags: jsf, el, resourcebundle

I am in a bit confusion.

That's how a JSF EL will work and how variable resolver involved while evaluating expressions like.

```
<h:outputlabel value="#{text.value}"/>
```

or

```
<h:outputlabel value="#{text['value']}"/>
```

Text refers to bundle var arg and value is the key in properties file.

Help me in understanding the evaluation of above expression when reading a property value from message properties.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Ganesh karanam

Answer (score 3):

JSF uses [Unified EL](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsf-el.htm#GJDDD) for evaluating expressions. The specification uses [ELResolvers](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/el/ELResolver.html) to determine the value of variables referenced in the expression.

The 'text' variable is likely getting stored in a standard scope (page, request, session, or application). The [ScopedAttributeELResolver](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/jsp/el/ScopedAttributeELResolver.html) handles looking up objects from these scopes. The object returned by the ELResolver for 'text' variable is then used as the base for resolving the 'value' property.

There is a [ResourceBundleELResolver](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/el/ResourceBundleELResolver.html) that knows how to access objects contained within a [ResourceBundle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html). The ResourceBundleELResolver will handle the looking up the 'value' property of the 'test' variable.