# JSF and EL, I don't understand this code (an array?)

Tags: jsf-2, managed-bean

I was reading some code and I found the next EL expression inside a JSF file:

```
  ${text['somefield']}
```

How is it work?.

Since I don't have access to the whole code, I can check what it is.   Is it "text" a managed bean?.

Because I could understand the next code:

```
  ${someBean.text['somefield']}
```

(accessing a field array inside a bean but it's not the case.

Comment: It is most likely a Map.

Comment: It can also be a field defined in the faces-context.xml , a resource bundle.

Comment: A map in any scope indeed (e.g. via CDI `@Producer`) or even something that is resolved via a custom EL resolver.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How JSF el expression works and when a JSF variable resolver will be involved while evaluating any JSF exprestion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33576739/how-jsf-el-expression-works-and-when-a-jsf-variable-resolver-will-be-involved-wh)

Answer (score 0):

`text` can be a managed bean, a CDI dependency (these are the 2 most likely)

`text['somefield']` is reading `somefield` field of `text` object. `text` is likely to be a map, but it could be a normal bean too. It's equivalent to `text.somefield`

In [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnahu.html#bnahx), you can also find similar exampes:

```
${customer.address["street"]}
```

Which is similar to:

```
${customer.address.street}
```

Comment: It can be way more... Just a HashMap that is somewhere put in the request scope (or any scope for that matter where EL in the current context has access to). It can be a resourcebundle... Or even something that can be resolved via a custom resolver...

Comment: @Kukeltje Yeah, right. I just wanted to mention the most likely ones, given the custom name `text` (at least for me, it's not recognizable as a built-in object/bean). You're welcome to edit this answer or post a different one. The more details, the better, I suppose...

Comment: Sort of... Most likely one for me is a resourcebundle...  But if you know upfront that your answer is not extensive, please state so. Otherwise newcomers might be confused...

Comment: And there is a duplicate ;-)